# Intellisense not responding correctly

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a very simple script for importing users from a CSV file

here is the code:

```
$filepath = import-csv "C:\Users\levl\OneDrive\Users Making script\Users-list.csv"
```

$users= $filepath

ForEach ($user in $users) {

`Get the users info
$firstname = $user

}`

The script is not completed because i couldn't make intellisense to complete the script.

after importing the csv file, when i try to write the "$user." Intellisense  not showing me the headers from the CSV file

here are the headers in the csv file:

First Name,Last Name,SamAccountName,Job Title,Department,Description,Path,ScriptPath

and intelisense is showing difrient headers as on the picture

[image: intelisense]

PS: when i run $users i get the list of the users as it has to be

Comment: Why don't you type the headers in full instead of relying solely on intellisense?
After all you are trying to assign all the values of `First Name` header to `$firstname`. In your `foreach` loop, you can try `$firstname = $user.'First Name'`.

Comment: becous i'm new to scripting (only 1 month +) so i need it to help me,
i've added a screenshot of the Headers that it show, the thing is that i don't have these headers in the CSV file

Comment: Aaah!
You are trying to get the properties of `$newusers` inside the `foreach` loop. That's why it is not showing you anything. Try `$firstname = $user.'First Name'` instead of `$firstname = $newusers.'First Name'` in your code.

Comment: i did that, and the thing is, that it's not showing any thing :\
i'm starting to think that something wrong with my CSV file, but i don't know what :\ becouse i'v started a new CSV file with difrient headers and i didn't had any problem :\

Comment: Does it not populate `$firstname`?
Did you check what `$user | Get-Member` return to you?
By using `Get-Member`, you can get all the properties and methods of your object.

Comment: yes my friend, i've checked and i've seen the right properties, look at the answer.. this is very strange :\

any way, in that way, it's working properly, and now i can accomplish my first Adding users script :)

Answer (score 0):

So in my case from some strange reason i had to run all the script even though it
wasn't completed, so that PowerShell will import the right properties, only after that i've started to see the right Properties according the csv file

so if you encounter with this strange issue when you don't see the right properties when you try to get all the info from the CSV file, try to write the first few lines in the ForEach loop and then it will start to show you the right properties.

that's why i like my profession, each day i learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the code snippet you posted, it's clear the ISE would have no idea what properties to present to you because until you run the first two lines it will be clueless about what the contents of $filepath or $newusers is (since the contents of the CSV are unknown to PowerShell until it loads it).

Once you run those lines, the variables are properly populated and the ISE is then able to interrogate the objects and present the right properties based on the actual contents of the file.

To complicate matters, you will see that there are examples that contradict this:

[image]

The reason this works is that the Get-Service lets PowerShell know what type of object it returns as part of its definition, so even before you run it PowerShell knows the results (the types anyway) that you will get.

Comment: The thing is, that i run the first lines and it didn't worked :\